# Efficiently change website body depending on day?

Tags: php, javascript, html

So I have a website, and I have a `txt` file with multiple lines with a date, then some text.
I can find how to parse the `txt` file to get what text goes with what date, but is there any way to make it so instead of every person who tries to load the page having the server do the logic and find out what text to display, just make the first person per day make the server find out what text to display then the server automatically displays that the rest of the day?

Comment: Is the load on your server so great that this is necessary?

Answer (score 2):

You can write the results to another file, sort of a cache system.

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$path = '/path/to/cache/';
$file = $path.$today;

// Does cache file exist? If not, make it
if ( ! is_file($file)) {
    // parse your text file, get content, write it to file
    file_put_contents($file, $txt_content);
}

$content = file_get_contents($file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the text file changing frequently? If not, it may just make more sense to introduce some javascript that checks the day and then writes the text that's written into a var by you. That way there's no parsing necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The other option, if you have server permissions, is to simply write a periodic script, such as a cron job to run daily on the server and update a file with the correct content.